# jquery .not selector causing error

Tags: jquery

the code:

```
 if (!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) == '5')){
        $('ul a span', '#menu'.not('{Developers}')).css('color', 'rgb(210,210,210)').hover(
            function(){ $(this).animate({color: 'rgb(255,255,255)'}, 500); },
            function(){ $(this).animate({color: 'rgb(210,210,210)'}, 200); }
        );
  }
```

Does this look like correct syntax? It's working, however it's throwing the error that .not is not a function.  I'm calling this function in a menu.js that my main page is loading. It's not in a document ready, and it is working, other than the error. If it weren't working, I'd say my core jq library wasn't loading first, but it is. Help is appreciated!  Note, :not does not work, so please don't suggest I use that. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your html code too ? Edit your question to do so please.

Comment: Can you give an HTML example of what you are trying to select? It would be unusual to use `not()` against an ID attribute, since IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to be using the jQuery function [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/), you need to call it on a jQuery object (currently you're trying to call it on a string). Here' an example:

```
$('ul a span', '#menu').not('{Developers}').css
                      ^--- changes here ---^
```

If you really mean ***selector*** as in your title, then it's `:not`, not `.not` ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation)), and it would need to be part of the selector string. But you said later in your question that you tried `:not` and it didn't work (I wasn't sure where or how you tried `:not`, though).

I think there's another problem with that code, because both `.not` and `:not` expect a selector (`.not` also allows an element/jQuery instance or function), and the selector `'{Developers}'` is invalid.

From your comment that it's working other than the exception, I can only surmise that something *else* is changing the background on the elements, because the code as quoted will fail (throw an exception, that is barring your having added a `not` function to `String.prototype`), and won't enter the `$` function at all, much less get to the `css` part of it.

If your goal is to color the background of the spans matching the selector `ul a span` under the element with the ID `menu` but *not* the span containing the text "{Developers}", you need to use the `:contains` pseudo-class (taken out of CSS3 but jQuery supports it):

```
$("#menu ul a span:not(:contains('{Developers}'))").css(...
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ajoqi3)

If you prefer the form that passes `#menu` as a context parameter instead:

```
$("ul a span", "#menu").not(":contains('{Developers}')").css(...
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ajoqi3/2) ...but jQuery will handle them both efficiently.

Comment: T.J. - I have a feeling that your first inclination was right, since the question states *"Note, :not does not work, so please don't suggest..."*. Makes it seem like what was tried was `'#menu:not(...'`. But who knows?

Comment: Yes, :not was tried. The {Developers} is literal content- it's a navigation title. Again, it does work, so the .not is being understood, everything but my {Developers} title is being colored light gray. However, fixing that extra parenthesis still didn't make the error go away.

Comment: @cdb: Unless you yourselves are adding a `not` function to the `String.prototype`, the code you've quoted throws an exception at `'#menu'.not(`. Something else may make it *appear* to work, but again without your having added a `not` function to `String`, the code you've quoted doesn't even go into the `$` function at all. Stepping back, what is the stuff prior to the `css` *supposed* to select?

Comment: @cdb: Actually, from your comment above, I think I can guess what you're trying to do. I've updated the answer to do that.

Comment: Thanks TJ, that's a super helpful example!

Comment: @cdb: Good deal, glad that helps!

Comment: I just noticed, works in IE $("ul a span", "#menu").not(":contains['{Developers}']['{Developers Menu}']").css('color', 'rgb(210,210,210)').hover(               but not Firefox. I added that second selector in there based off of what you exemplified. Did I do that correctly? I guess not since FF isn't playing.

Comment: @cdb: You've added square brackets to the bit I gave you which shouldn't be there. I don't know what you're trying to do with the second part you've added.

Comment: I just want two different selectors, both of those are content tabs that I don’t want affected by the function. -I was wondering about the square brackets. I saw another example somwhere with them, I thought mabye they were to be used with concatenated elements. It seemed to work ,that is until I checked FF.

Comment: You can chain `.not` calls:  `$("ul a span", "#menu").not(":contains({Developers})").not(":contains({Developers Menu})").css` or of course `$("#menu ul a span:not(:contains({Developers}):not(:contains({Developers Menu})").css`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you pasted the code correctly, you're missing a ')'

[jQuery .not() info](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
if (!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) == '5')){
        $('ul a span', '#menu').not('{Developers}').css('color', 'rgb(210,210,210)').hover(
            function(){ $(this).animate({color: 'rgb(255,255,255)'}, 500); },
            function(){ $(this).animate({color: 'rgb(210,210,210)'}, 200); }
        );
  }
```

Comment: +1 Yeah, you got there faster than I did (though I did get there). I kept staring at the expression trying to make a CSS selector out of it. Then I finally realized the second part (`#menu`) was a context, and realized he meant the `.not` *function*. I got so stuck on *selectors*...

Comment: (She) did mean the .not function :)

Answer (score 1):

I can see  a **typo** in you code.

```
if (!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) == '5')){
  $('ul a span', '#menu').not('{Developers}').css('color', 'rgb(210,210,210)').hover(
    function(){ $(this).animate({color: 'rgb(255,255,255)'}, 500); },
      function(){ $(this).animate({color: 'rgb(210,210,210)'}, 200); }
    );
}
```

In your code you have

```
 $('ul a span', '#menu'.not('{Developers}')).css...
```

but it should be

```
$('ul a span', '#menu').not('{Developers}').css...
```

You are missing one parenthesis and you need one too.

Answer (score 0):

... `$('ul a span', '#menu').not(` ....
Missing a parenthesis I think? Or was it supposed to be part of the selector?

Comment: This brings up a good question, is a selector considered separate from a function, being that it's inside a function?

Comment: So, what I have now,  just to be clear is:   if (!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) == '5')){ 
        $('ul a span', '#menu').not('{Developers}').css('color', 'rgb(210,210,210)').hover( 
            function(){ $(this).animate({color: 'rgb(255,255,255)'}, 500); }, 
            function(){ $(this).animate({color: 'rgb(210,210,210)'}, 200); } 
        );